# Get Total Results Youtube Api PHP

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Hey, well right now I'm parsing youtube's api

demo url :

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/test?orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=50
```

i'm using simplexml_load_file

the thing is, what should i do to retrieve the

```
<openSearch:totalResults>9477</openSearch:totalResults>
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=test&orderby=viewCount&start-index=1&max-results=1";
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$counts = $sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
$total = $counts->totalResults;
```

Comment: I am using `v=2` and this method does not work. Any idea how to get this going on `v2`?